# html5 video with partial content 206

Tags: html, video, partial

I'm sending from my server partial contents (206) with length 1mb. But video player does not make buffer this and make new request only if SHOWED this partial content. And if client has slow internet, he get delay, while new request executed. How may make buffer partial content? I would that browser make new request, when partial content full LOADED, but not SHOWED else.

Answer (score 1):

A 206 can only be returned when the browser asks for a range via the  Content-Range header. Then the server must fulfill the requested range exactly as requested with a 206. If the browser does not specify a Content-Range header, returning a 206 is illegal. You, as the server can not force the browser to make a range request, but you can tell it your server can accept ranges via the Accept-Ranges header.

Comment: Your don't understand me. Video is works. I'm only want win delay.

Comment: I think what he meant was: user requests for 1st 1024 bytes of info for example. Server respond with 1024 bytes of info. Client make another request for the next 1024 bytes of info at the point when video player finished playing the first 1024 bytes of data. This process keeps going on and client have a bad video viewing experience as he has to wait for each subsequent response. Is there any way for the client to start requesting the next 1024 bytes before the 1st 1024 bytes "run out"?